# How to take the backup of datanode in the hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop

Where as i find many solutions for taking the back up of metadata in name node and would like to know how to take the back up of datanode? leaving replication factor aside but want to know the detail process to take the back up of data node in the production level for 20 node cluster.

Comment: I think you want to backup a whole table rather than a particular data node.

Comment: Table? I want to back up entire data of the datanode X (name of the datanode) in the cluster and could some one also explain the procedure to take the  datanode X out of the cluster and need to take the back up of the whole data of the X datanode  and need to fix the same to the cluster again

Comment: you should start from HBase basic guide. you can have 10 nodes in  your cluster and HBase table would be spread across these nodes. taking a backup of a single node does not make much sense

Comment: Could you please explain in steps for example 1)Stop zookeeper 2)stop datanode 3)stop yarn services.... which really helps me

Answer (score 0):

distcp command in hadoop, can copy data from source clusster to target 
for example :

`hadoop distcp hftp://cdh57-namenode:50070/hbase hdfs://CDH59-nameservice/hbase`

this command copy hbase folder from cdh57-namenode to CDH59-nameservice

more information can obtain from this link
https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/cdh_admin_distcp_data_cluster_migrate.html